# Debugging a Corrupted Object on the Heap

Tags: c++, gdb, valgrind, lldb

I'm debugging a non-trivial software project where I have a bunch of objects located on the heap. At some point in time (at least) one of these objects gets corrupted.

I added a const member to my class to serve as a canary and indeed, it gets corrupted during executing. Typically I'd add a watchpoint to this variable to figure out when the memory is written to. However, I don't know which instance gets overwritten, as any information stored in the class gets corrupted as well.

I have too many objects to set a watchpoint on each of them and I haven't been able to reproduce with a smaller input set. Running valgrind I see "Invalid read of size 4", which is my canary int of 4 bytes being read but at this point it's already too late.

Any suggestions on how to proceed from here?

Comment: Title: "on the Heap". Question: "on the stack". Please make up your mind.

Comment: Are some of your objects deleted before the corruptions happen ? 'Invalid read of size 4' means you're reading data you shouldn't, like freed memory, or outside of an allocated memory block.
Doesn't valgrind provide more information ?
Can you post the full valgrind trace ?

Comment: Review the source code.   What are you doing that may cause such corruption to occur?   Is the program multithreaded and proper synchronization was not used?  Are the pointers to these objects being shared, and one of the owners may have deallocated the memory without informing the other owners?  Etc. Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out what was causing my issue. Turns out the object I was looking at never existed in the first place. Like @employed-russian, I wondered  whether my object might have been deleted somewhere I wasn't aware of. Putting a breakpoint on the destructor yielded nothing so the only reasonable explanation is the pointer itself being invalid, pointing to memory that wasn't a valid instance of my class.

Lo and behold; the pointer I was dereferencing was left uninitialized by some constructor of another class. I figured it out when I added an explicit check for null and Valgrind's error became `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`. By using `--track-origins=yes`, I quickly figured out the source of the uninitialized data, i.e. the pointer missing from the initialization list.

(I know uninitialized values can be detected by the compiler with `-Wuninitialized` but apparently my version of clang (apple) didn't feel like mentioning it with `-Wall` enabled.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably this won't be specific enough, but when I had a similar problem, here is what I ended up doing. I'm assuming you can reproduce your problem in a deterministic fashion.

My strategy was to find which instance caused the problem first. This I did with a counter on a specific line that exposes the symptom. For example, on Visual Studio, I would setup a breakpoint that triggers on the 100000th hit, so that it never does; but Visual Studio still tells you how many times the breakpoint is encountered during execution. By trial and error, I would find that the problem occurs on the say, 20th time the breakpoint is encountered, and so I would set the breakpoint to trigger on the 19th iteration, to be able to discriminate the appropriate instance before corruption occurred.

Starting from there, I could have the address of the variable that was corrupted before it was, and play with the debugger to find out what is going on: gather enough information about the faulty instance.

Then, I did setup breakpoints at strategic places, which were triggered by conditions : eg. trigger only for an instance with the appropriate address, or with specific values in members.

You'll probably get to when the symptom occurs precisely, but not to the problem, but that's still something.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This sounds like an interesting approach, I'll definitely keep it in mind for future debugging sessions!

Answer (score 1):

> Running valgrind I see "Invalid read of size 4", which is my canary int of 4 bytes being read but at this point it's already too late.

You are confused: if valgrind told you that you are doing invalid read (presumably because the object has been freed), then you are reading *danging* (already freed) object, and that is *exactly* your problem.

You shouldn't try to access such objects, and the fact that your canary has been changed / corrupted after you freed / deleted the object is irrelevant.